# How do I create function handle from cfit, multiply with other function handle and integrate the term?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, numerical-integration, function-handle

I try to get an integral of two function handles in Matlab. The first function handle would be a weibull probability density function and the second function handle is based on a cfit I created with linear interpolation of single points.

```
x = 0:0.1:35;
fun1 = @(x) wblpdf(x,weibullAlpha,weibullBeta);
fun2 = @(x) feval(cfitObject,x);
fun3 = @(x) (fun(x).*fun2(x));
y = integral(fun3,0,35); % Using quad(fun3,0,35) doesn't work either.
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 515)
Output of the function must be the same size as the input. If FUN is an array-valued  integrand,
set the 'ArrayValued' option to true.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
            finalInputChecks(x,fx);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
        [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
    [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in test (line 7) % "test" is the name of the script file.
y = integral(fun3,0,35);
```

The problem must have to do something with "fun2" since the code works just fine with e.g.

```
fun2 = x.^2;
```

Note: if I plot fun2 with the cfitObject I don't get an error. It's also possible to integrate the function using quad().

```
x = 0:0.1:35;
fun2 = @(x) feval(cfitObject,x);
y = quad(fun2,0,35);
plot(x, fun2(x))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `y = integral(fun3,0,35, 'ArrayValued', 1);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be ok. Probably the problem is that `fun2` cannot take vectorized input, it could be resolved by modifying `fun2` (`cfitObject`) to be able to handle vector input or telling the software that the function in the integral is array valued:

```
y = integral(fun3, 0, 35, 'ArrayValued', 1);
```